# Trying to show g++ (linter-gcc for Atom) where to find Arduino libs

Tags: library, compile, gcc

I'm trying to use Atom as an IDE for arduino and arduino-based boards.
I'm using arduino-cli for compilation and avrdude for upload, and now I'm trying to use linter-gcc for linting.

g++ is running and the linter seems to be working ok, but it's can't find built in libs.  I've added:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\*"
```

to my GCC include paths, I've also tried copying the lib sources to my working directory, but I'm still getting (e.g.):

```
SPI.h: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas why gcc isn't seeing SPI.h?

Comment: If you are using Atom, why not just download Platform.io running on Atom as your Arduino IDE? It saves you all the trouble of using arduino-cli

Comment: TBH I don't want all the weight of Platform.io - I have my toolchain well established with avrdude etc and to my knowledge the platform.io environment is really set up for serial programming of prototype boards like Arduinos rather than my ICSP programming and fuse-setting of mostly custom short-run boards.